# Log out facebook from Xamarin.forms app

Tags: c#, facebook, xamarin.forms

I am a newbie in xamarin forms, I am trying to log out from facebook in my app , I made some reacher and I find this code :

```
NSHttpCookieStorage storage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;

    foreach (NSHttpCookie cookie in storage.Cookies) 
    {
      if(cookie.Domain == ".facebook.com")
      {
        storage.DeleteCookie(cookie);
      }

    }
```

The things is NSHttpCookieStorage  is not refenced (I have tried Ctrl+Alt) 
Do you know the NugetPakages for Xamarin.forms , please ?

I am working in xamarin.forms

If you have a better solution I will take ,thanks in advance

Comment: Are you in the iOS project? Because Ns-Classes are iOS specific.

Comment: @ DogeAmazed I am in Xamarin.Forms project